# Git-repo command: I have delete my entire local project

Tags: git

I have accidently deleted my entire repository beside 2 random files. Here is how it happened. I wanted to upload my local project to a new github repository but one file (an image) that I had already deleted was blocking the push because it was too heavy (>100M or something). Since I had already deleted the file, I found out online that it must have cached and saved in history by git so I tried to delete that file with the following command:

```
git filter-repo --path theme/static/img/founder_infos2.png --force
```

I have tried:

```
git restore --source=HEAD~1 /core/
```

Rollback does not work either because my commits history seem to have gone away too

To summarize, absolutely everything has been deleted from my repository and I can't find a way to get it back, I am not that experienced working with git and I may have undo a month worth of work so any help would be welcome

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend; it will show which commit each of your branch heads referred to previously so you can reset them with `git reset`. Most likely nothing has been *deleted* from the repository, only from your working directory. The rest of the commits are still there, but not currently reachable from any branch head.

Comment: you forced to have some files deleted, now what is your programming question?

Comment: thank you, I will try working with git reflog and update my question with the results.Hopefully it works out

Comment: @chepner the purpose of  `git-filter-repo --force` is precisely to get rid of those long hanging precious files

Comment: @PA. I understand it was a pretty dumb to use a command I do not know about or study beforehand. I assumed (wrongly) that it would delete that one specific file. My programming question is about restoring a repository from where it was before

Comment: I confused it with `filter-branch`. I hope the OP has a backup of the repository.

Comment: I dont think I do unfortunately. I get how forcing delete on a specific file is deleting everything with it

Comment: precisely, you use `git -filter-repo`  to rewrite your Git history and remove a file from every commit that it was involved with

Comment: yes, as you say, remove a file, the one mentioned in the command, weird that everything is deleted with it

Comment: your changes are not lost : a. run `git reflog`, b. scroll in the list to spot the commit *before* you unwillingly deleted your content and copy the hash for that commit, c. run `git reset --hard <hash>`

Comment: `git filter-repo` normally insists that you work in a *fresh clone* so that it doesn't destroy the original (because you still have the original from before cloning). If you worked the way filter-repo says you should, just go back to the original clone. If you didn't use a fresh clone, find a (system level) backup of the original clone, e.g., on your Time Machine drive.

Comment: I unfortunately acted like a fool and just used one commad without looking further. That's my mistake and learning it the hard way

Answer (score 1):

Your changes are not lost :

1. run `git reflog`,
2. scroll in the list to spot the commit *before* you unwillingly deleted your content and copy the hash for that commit,
3. run `git reset --hard <hash>`

---

Your misuse of `git filter-repo` is : it turns out "keep *only* the files or directory I mention" is also a handy command, and that's the one you executed by running `git filter-repo --path theme/static/img/founder_infos2.png`.

To *drop these elements* and keep everything else: you must add the `--invert-paths` option :

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path theme/static/img/founder_infos2.png
```

---

links to doc :

from the project's Readme, you can easily go to the ["How do I use it?"](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-use-it) section and click on the [user manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) link.

On that user manual page, scroll down to the [EXAMPLES](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) section.

The first paragraph is about path filtering, and the second example shows you how to use `--invert-paths` to drop some files.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately git reflog output ```fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet```. Everything has been whiped out it looks like